# Beginner: tolower in a vector

Tags: c++

So I have a code for counting different characters in a textfile and I dont quite understand what the bottom codeline in the following section do:

```
string linje;
int nLetters = 'Z' - 'A' +1;
vector<int> bokstaver(nLetters, 0);
int antallTegn = 0;

while(getline(inputfile, linje)){
    for(char tegn:linje){
        if(isLetter(tegn)){
            antallTegn++;
            bokstaver[tolower(tegn)-'a']++;
```

I know it converts the tegn variable to a lower case but I dont understand why we have to subtract 'a'.

Comment: To get the 0-based position of a letter, in an alphabet, so you could use it as an index..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Characters are represented by integers in computers. Each integer value represent a character (this gets more complicated with UNICODE, but that's beyond the scope of this question). So, 'a' has a numerical value, as does `tolower(tegn)`.

Numbers can be thought as a line of numbers, where the value is the position of the number on that line. Similarly, number-encoded characters can be thought of as characters in a line where their numerical value is their position.

A number line:

```
0 1 2 3 4
```

A character line:

```
, . - a b c d
```

Subtraction of two numbers is analogous to their distance on the number line. Similarly, subtracting two characters is their distance on the character line.

So, `bokstaver` is an array whose indices are positions on the character line, offset by the position of the character `'a'`.

Comment: So if I understand it correctly:

Let say "tegn" is "B", then it will convert it to a lower case b and the dedeuct "a" value a so we get element 1 of the vector and it will increase that element with 1?

Comment: @SuchARush ... if we assume that `'b'` is one value greater than `'a'`. This is true for all character encodings that I know of, but not guaranteed by the C++ standard.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much for the answers. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Characters are represented using *character codes* in computers.

For example, character code representing for `a` is 0x61 (97) in ASCII code.

Therefore, you have to subtract `'a'` (character code for `a`) in order to convert the character code in the input string to index for the vector starting with zero.

This method will work when character codes for alphabets are continuous. ASCII code satisfies this condition.

Comment: Thank you so much, appreciate the answer :)